# Is there a way to have a macro remove all paragraphs of a certain type?

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph

Im creating an invoice Word Template on basis of Words Mail Merge. I get the necessary information via .csv file from a web application and create a table based on these informations. The data is given this way:

```
Person1 - InvoicePos1 - InvoicePos2 - InvoicePos3 - InvoicePos4
Person2 - InvoicePos1 - InvoicePos2 - InvoicePos3 - InvoicePos4
Person3 - InvoicePos1 - InvoicePos2 - InvoicePos3 - InvoicePos4
                              .
                              .
                              .
                              .
```

There are different amounts of invoice types/ invoice positions so i have to create a dynamic table which works great so far.

My problem:
Word seems to automatically inserts a paragraph before each table that gets insert via a {IF}-Statement. Why do i know that its Word that inserts these paragraphs? Well the whole document is in Calibri size 12 but these Paragraphs are Times New Roman 10.

[IMGUR-Link with (hopefully helpful images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL58F.jpg)

My question: Is there a way to create a macro that runs over the created document that disables/ hides each paragraph that is Times New Roman?

Ive tried different settings already to try to prevent the creation of these paragraphs but to no avail. So now im trying to hide these paragraphs after the document is created.

```
Sub HidePara()
    If /FoundParagraphs/.Font.Name = "Times New Roman" Then 
        /FoundParagraphs/.Hidden = true
    End If 
End Sub
```

I know how to change the Hidden Attribute (which isnt hard at all .. )
But how would i look for either all paragraph marks (i would have to use the If-statement ive given) or (which would be better imho) filter for all paragraphs of the .Font.Name "Times New Roman".
I cant find any way to find the paragraph marks at all. But than again im pretty new to VBA and actually have no idea what im doing here. As VBA is really great. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even faster is a simple Find/Replace:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete them:

```
Sub DelPara()
Dim oPara As Paragraph
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If oPara.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman" Then oPara.Range.Delete
Next oPara
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Searched for Find all Paragraphs on google and the only thing ive found was .Find ... why wasnt As Paragraphs an option. Works perfectly!

Comment: I finally had time to fiddle around with the other answer a bit and it actually is more pracitcal in my opinion as i can search for more different variables. Its more useful to run the other answer in a Macro where i can insert different values for Font.Name, .Text and such. It still worked like a charm!